# Docker with Plesk: Random Container spawned

Tags: docker, plesk

I played around with Docker and followed this [Tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/). 
Using the docker functionality in Plesk, I pulled my created container from docker hub and ran it. When trying to remove it again, it threw an error message, which I didnt capture (didnt expected anything strange at that point). Then, when going back to the container overview it gave me the screen shown below.

Now, the container in the middle is mine (get-started), however, where the hell did angry_kare and peaceful_haibt come from?

Thank you guys for any answers or ideas! :)

(Im am currently not able to reproduce this :/)

[Random containers spawned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBx0S.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the container without a name. Docker will create containers with random names. The two containers which your having are the previously failed containers.

Comment: Thank you! I already expected some hacker'ish guy with bad humor behind it o.O :D